# Python pandas empty dataframe while appending dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file, delimiter= ','))
df = df.append({
               "date" : date,
               "time" : time,
               "query": query,
               "response": response
        }, ignore_index=True)

#it results in an empty dataframe any ideas over it?
```

Comment: Can you add sample content of the "file" as well?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to print your df before appending your new variable? there's nothing wrong with your code, just 3 possibilities, your CSV and your variable is empty, you didn't print your variable `print(df)`, or it returns an error that you didn't mention.